# Rails - Understanding how to Query An Objectin Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

if I have the following:

```
@projects = Permission.where(["user_id >= ?", 21])
```

Results In:

```
[#<Permission id: 59, project_id: 13, user_id: 21>, #<Permission id: 59, project_id: 13, user_id: 21>]
```

I then what to use those project_id 's to QUERY as follows:

```
AuditLog.where({ :project_id => @projects }).limit(10)
```

But this errors?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `project_id' for [#<Permission id: 59, project_id: 13, user_id: 21>]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Ideas? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, let's clean up your first query:

```
@permissions = Permission.where(['user_id >= ?', 21])
```

This is less misleading about what `@permissions` is actually storing.  Next, remember that it's an array, and what you're saying in the next query is "where project_id is a list of ruby permission objects", and that doesn't make a valid query.

You can get the info you want, though.  First, use ruby's `array.map` method to walk through all permissions and gather their project_id's:

```
@project_ids = @permissions.map(&:project_id)
```

Now you can tell the database to grab all audit logs where the project_id is in the list:

```
@audit_logs = AuditLog.where(['project_id in (?)', @project_ids])
```

That should give you what you need.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You had ">=" in your original query, so I copied that.  But it makes more sense that you're looking for exact matches in most situations.